# How to get the hierarchy viewer of other apps in Android?

Tags: android, hierarchical-data

I know it's possible to get my own apps' hierarchy viewer, but is there any way we can also retrieve this from other running apps in Android?

Comment: Use **`uiautomatorviewer`**. It does not provide quite as much detail as does Hierarchy View, but it works on production devices and can inspect any app.